# What does "all the more so" mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Hello I'd like to know what "all the more so" means in the following context?
My understanding is "it becomes more certain that the lifetime of the system is endless if we never replace ...". Is my understanding correct?

To confuse the accountants more, the current system of capitalizing and depreciating the value of the system requires gauging the expected life of the system—the period in which we will use it to generate profits. But if we continue to “maintain” the system in a way that avoids a Big-Bang transformation, then its lifetime is effectively endless. **All the more so** if we never replace the system, just slowly change it piece by piece until it no longer resembles the original.

Comment: **All the more so** is another way of saying **even more so** or **even more the case** or **even truer**. That's to say: the statement applies more strongly in these circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then, "the statement" in your comment means the previous statement ("its lifetime is effectively endless")?

Comment: That is correct. **All the more so...** serves to emphasise/amplify this statement.